# @PostConstruct not called when using Mockito @Spy annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, mockito

I am using Spring, TestNG and Mockito frameworks. I am writing a unit test for a class *A* that has a dependency on class *B*. Class *B* has a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

While writing Unit test case using TestNG for class *A*, I am annotating an instance of class *B* with Mockito `@Spy` in the test class. I can see the instance of *B* being created properly by Mockito. But **why** `@PostConstruct` code **is not called** when Mockito is processing `@Spy` annotation?

So, what I have done is I moved the code inside `@PostConstruct` to the *constructor*.

Is there any way to make Mockito execute any 'Post-processing' method while processing `@Spy` annotation?

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, there isn't. PostConstruct is a Spring concept. But nothing forbids you to call it in your setup method:

```
@Before
public void prepare() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.b.postConstruct();
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. So, could you please advice me whether is it a good approach to avoid PostConstruct and use constructor? What is the advantage of PostConstruct over constructor? Please explain

Comment: In PostConstruct, you have access to all the dependencies injected to the bean and to all the properties set in the bean by the container, after the bean has been constructed. In the constructor, you don't.

Comment: It is javax.annotation.PostConstruct. So it isn't a Spring concept.

Comment: @CollinPeters: it's not stricto sensu a Spring concept, but it's an annotation that is used by the dependency injection framework being used, which in this case, is Spring. The point is that Mockito doesn't care about this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing the method labeled with @PostConstruct by the constructor of the class labeled @Inject.
Both solutions do the same and are supported by Mockito.
It is necessary to put dependence:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Before:

```
@Service
    public class AddressMapper extends CommonMapper {   
        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {
            ....
```

After:

```
@Service
    public class AddressMapper extends CommonMapper {
        @Inject
        public AddressMapper() {
            ...
```